# gem conflict oa-oauth and fb_graph on the multi_json gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, fb-graph

how do i solve this kind of conflict?

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "multi_json":
  In Gemfile:
    fb_graph (= 2.6.2) ruby depends on
      multi_json (>= 1.3) ruby

    oa-oauth (= 0.3.2) ruby depends on
      multi_json (1.0.4)
```

my gem file:

```
# oauth authentication
gem 'oa-oauth', '0.3.2', :require => 'omniauth/oauth'
gem 'oa-openid', '0.3.2'
gem 'fb_graph', '2.6.2'
gem 'twitter', '4.4.4'
gem "koala", '1.6.0'
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try: add `gem "multi_json` in your Gemfile, delete your Gemfile.lock file, then run `bundle` again.